# Can MySQL Cluster match NoSQL performance in heavy throghput with heavy writes

Tags: mysql, database, nosql, scalability, throughput

Im designing a turned based strategy game that allows Players to save game states so they can play/resume games at their leisure. This creates a data environment in which there could be potentially large amounts of concurrent reads/writes happening. Furthermore, within the context of the game, many different variables are available to the Players that allow them to transform the data.

We've intentionally implemented a turn based design to help mitigate the amount of concurrent reads/writes, however it will still result in a very dynamic gaming environment in which data will constantly transform (obviously given that its a game, there will likely be a 1:1 read to write ratio) and, given its dynamics, probably be suited far better to schema-free design.

What I'd like to know at this point is if anyone has seen how well MySQL cluster performs in an environment like this? Will it perform as well as a NoSQL solution like Couchbase or Riak? Which would perform better (as a whole) for a write intensive environment?  Which would be more consistent in its access times of that data at its peak throughput?  Also, which would keep closest (and fastest) to ACID compliance-- data versioning is very important, even if it is a turn based game, Players should be able to see their choices reflected immediately-- without running into troublesome locks and whatnot.

Comment: I am _not_ voting to close this. _Only_ because I bothered reading the entire question. From your title this is an immediate "unappropriate" question as there is no correct answer, see the [faq]. Your question is very densely written and it's difficult to find the actual question. I can't guarantee that other people will agree with me; from the title alone you're likely to wind up with little help. Can you put at least a little summary at the top to clarify the emphasis?

Comment: Ok, thanks Ben.  Ill try and break this down so its easier to approach!